# How do i get the same font as cmd uses?

Tags: c++, windows, fonts, gdi

With `GDI` i want to make a program and i want to use the same `bitmap` as `cmd` uses.

I want to make a `HFONT` using `CreateFontA` or a `HBITMAP` using `CreateBitmap`.

I have searched on

- [https://msdn.microsoft.com/](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for `CreateFont`,
- [https://msdn.microsoft.com/](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183485%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for `CreateBitmap`.

And i don't think they are the best documented sources online, I didn't understand them so well.

Could i get some `help` or `documentations` i would appreciate it.

Thanks :)

## EDIT

With `GDI` i want to make a `text editor` and i want to use the same `bitmap` as `cmd` uses.

Why, is that i want to use all `RGB Colors`.

How would i get the `bitmap` / `font` if i only want to use `CreateFontA` or `CreateBitmap`.

Thanks. :)

Comment: Those are examples of very well documented functions. What is exact problem? [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) You will need to [show some effort](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) in order to get any help from programmers community. For now your post looks like ["Unclear what you're asking"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)

Comment: You want help with font, bitmap, color, gdi, text editor... You are really asking for a book or a tutorial. You can search for this term "Win32 project tutorial".